# "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas>=1.2.3"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, openai-api

How to fix this error in Python?

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas>=1.2.3
```

Comment: did you try to install pandas of version `1.2.3` or above?

Comment: what is the output of `pip list`? Looks like `pip uninstall pandas` and install new, or just `pip install --upgrade pandas`.

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh   What is the right command for installing pandas version higher or equal to 1.2.3? Thanks a lot.

Comment: depending on your manager, it could be `pip install pandas`, or `conda install pandas`, or something else you're using.

Comment: @xtlc It shows the version is only 1.1.5, but why does running "pip uninstall pandas" take so long like forever? Thanks.

Comment: lots of dependencies ... this can take a while, pandas is huge. Did it work in the end?

Comment: `python --version` ? `pip --version` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to install pandas version higher or equal to  1.2.3

execute to install newer version of pandas

`pip install pandas`

Comment: What is the right command for installing pandas version higher or equal to 1.2.3? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This command installs a newer version of pandas. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me by upgrading pip, something like this
/opt/venv/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip